# How to keep some formatting and paragraphs when using jsPDF?

Tags: jquery, html, pdf, pdf-generation, jspdf

Okay, so I have a basic table for a schedule I created for a gym.  I want to be able to download that table using jsPDF. As of right now, I've been able to get the table downloading fine, however there are a few things I just can't get to work.

First,  I cannot, for the life of me, get the table to be full width within the PDF that get's downloaded. I've read dozens of posts about jsPDF and nothing has been able to solve the problem!

Second, the information within each cell is in 3 different `p` tags and therefore should be on three different lines, but it is jumbling the lines together.

Third, I would like the cells to remain text aligned center.

The jsFiddle below shows as far as I've gotten, but these last three items are really starting to bug me, and I've researched the heck out of it with no luck...

http://jsfiddle.net/xzZ7n/695/

```
function demoFromHTML() {
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
source = $('#editor')[0];

specialElementHandlers = {
    // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
    '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
        // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
        return true
    }
};
margins = {
    top: 30,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40,
    width: '100%'
};

pdf.fromHTML(
source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
margins.left, // x coord
margins.top, { // y coord
    'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
},

function (dispose) {

    pdf.save('Test.pdf');
}, margins);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) and then use `pdf.addHTML()` instead of `pdf.fromHTML()`. It works great. I used it and it kept all my styles from the page.

Here's my code:

```
 var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
 pdf.addHTML($('#NameOfTheElementYouWantToConvertToPdf')[0], function () {
     pdf.save('Test.pdf');
 });
```

Comment: I added it to the server, but now when it renders the PDF, it is completely black.  Is there any way you could possible explain this method a little more?

Comment: Make sure you set the background color to white.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. I'm looking through html2canvas' documentation, and I can't find anything

Comment: When I used it, I discovered that Bootstrap, the CSS framework I use, had the background set to black and that I needed to set the background color of some HTML tags to white. I'm hoping that's the case for you too because otherwise I don't know what would be causing it. I updated my answer to include the code I'm using. I'm not really doing anything special there.

Comment: Its actually not Bootstrap that is causing the black background. Apparently the PDF defaults to a black background. You need to explicitly set the background to white. At least in my instance.

Comment: Be sure to have the background color style of the section set to the desired color to avoid a black background!

Comment: It only takes screen shot of current screen. It does not take whole page if scroller is present on page.

Comment: @Anky, is the scrollbar on the element you are trying to convert to PDF? If so, I wonder if referencing an element inside the scrolling container would make a difference.

Comment: @adam0101 there is no scrollbar on my page as i am using modal from angular 2.